# How to remove an event listener using forEach

Tags: javascript

How do I remove an event listener after creating an event listener in a forEach loop? The forEach loop runs immediately and the conditional I have to determine whether the event should be removed is ran immediately.

```
function play(){
    let arr = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    let remove = false;
    arr.forEach((value,index)=> {
        value.addEventListener("click", () => {
            remove = true;
        });
    }
    if(remove === true){
        arr.forEach((value, index)=>{
            value.removeEventListener("click", ()=>{

            });
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to remove the event listener? After first click?

Comment: Then dont execute the remove condition immediately.

Comment: `removeEventListener` requires the original function that was passed to `addEventListener` not a similar one. So with the current code you have you would need to remove the element and re-add it.

Answer (score 6):

`removeEventListener` needs to be called with the same function as was used in `addEventListener`. You can't use an anonymous function, because each instance is a different function. Define a named function and use that.

```
function myClickHandler() {
    remove = true;
}
arr.forEach(value => value.addEventListener("click", myClickHandler));
if (remove) {
    arr.forEach(value => value.removeEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
}
```